# Why Executors create Executor use LinkedBlockingQueue instead of ConcurrentLinkedQueue

Tags: java, concurrency, locking, java.util.concurrent

```
public static ExecutorService newFixedThreadPool(int nThreads) {
        return new ThreadPoolExecutor(nThreads, nThreads,
                                      0L, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS,
                                      new LinkedBlockingQueue<Runnable>());
    }
```

Use LinkedBlockingQueue, But does [ConcurrentLinkedQueue](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ConcurrentLinkedQueue.html) should be more efficient , which is no-blocking and lock free?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer is simple: `ConcurrentLinkedQueue` is not a `BlockingQueue`, but `LinkedBlockingQueue` is. The `ThreadPoolExecutor` [constructors](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ThreadPoolExecutor.html#constructor_summary) expect `BlockingQueue`s, so that `Executors` creates instances also with other implementations of `BlockingQueue`, like `SynchronousQueue` or `ArrayBlokingQueue` (depending on the factory method you call in `Executors`).

So, the more general question is: why `BlockingQueue` and not a simple `Queue`. And here the answer is again simple: the `BlockingQueue` interface has more useful methods. E.g a method tell if an element could be inserted in the queue without violating the capacity restrictions (and without throwing Exception, check [`BlockingQueue.offer()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/BlockingQueue.html#offer%28E%29)). Or some methods block if the queue has no elements (which again has a timed `poll()` and not timed version `take()`). So, if you would check the implementation of the ThreadPoolExecutor, you would see that it calls these convenient methods that miss in the `Queue` interface.

Answer (score 1):

If you submit Runnable objects to the queue and there are no running threads to consume those tasks, they of course will not be executed. When the queue becomes empty, the pool must block and wait for more tasks. So, to implement this behavior we are using BlockingQueue while interacting with pool.

Comment: yes, that's right, the worker (``getTask()`` method) will blocked on workerQueue, when no task is valid